# How to reproduce the "old" Peano's symbol for set inclusion

Tags: support, mathjax

In his *Arithmetices Principia Novo Methodo Exposita* (1889) [see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253991/bourbaki-and-set-inclusion) Giuseppe Peano used an $\text {"inverted C"}$ for *set inclusion* (modern : $\subset$).

There is a way to "invert" the alphabetic letters in formulae ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So Peano used $a \supset b$ to say "$a$ is contained in $b$", if I understand correctly? (That's confusing :/) Anyway, the command is `\supset`.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi - Thanks, but I know it ... In order to convey the "historical" aspect of the old symbols, I'm asking for a way to "ivert" (right-to-left) - if possible - some alphabetic symbols, like $C$ and $D$, used in that way by Peano and Russell ... :)

Comment: Ah, you literally want the symbol $C$ but flipped horizontally, without any other modifications? It's possible in latex (with `\reflectbox`), but I don't know if it is in mathjax. `\reflectbox` doesn't exist at least.

Comment: There is a way to rotate a box in LaTeX, and therefore you can rotate a C by 180 degrees. Further vertical and horizontal shifting might also be needed. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/93797/how-to-rotate-text-inline

Comment: Thanks @Najib ...

Comment: In MathJaX you can use unicode. Maybe U+2183 or U+2184 is similar to what you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudian_letters http://www.fileformat.info/convert/text/upside-down-map.htm Or maybe you can find some other unicode characters which will suit you.